# Kinvey API Console - JSONParseError

Tags: json, rest, kinvey

When I do a simple query on the Kinvey API Console I get

```
{
  "error": "JSONParseError",
  "description": "Unable to parse the JSON in the request",
  "debug": "Unexpected end of input"
}
```

Query example: /appdata/:appKey/:collectionName/?query={"_id":"3"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an engineer at Kinvey, and should be able to help ya out with this but I might need some more information.

Three things:  Your query looks properly formatted, so I don't think that's the problem.

Secondly, Make sure your `HTTP Method` is set to GET,

and finally,  in the `URL target` field you can let the website autocomplete `/appdata/:appkey/:collectionName:/` for your specific app and collection, and all you want to do is append your query `?query={"_id":"3"}` to the end of that autogenerated URL.

Then, click Send Request.

If that doesn't work, please post a comment about what the result is and I can follow up!

Answer (score 0):

You have to click anywhere in the site before clicking on the "Send Request" button, so that it convert the characters to code, in the url